# Eloquent Laravel Relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables 1 called clubs and 1 teams
This is how they look like

```
matches:
id   ||   home_id   ||    away_id   ||
--------------------------------------
1         2               1

clubs:
id   ||    name     ||    img_url    ||
---------------------------------------
1          Team1          .....
2          Team2          .......
```

Now I want to make a relation so I can get the club name through the home_id and away_id

Comment: Have you read the documentation? What have you tried?

Comment: I have read the documentation but I'm not sure which relationship I should use

Comment: The `matches` table will have a `belongsTo` relationship with `clubs`, while the `clubs` table will have a `hasOne` relationship to `matches`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match model:

```
public function club() { return $this->belongsTo('Match', 'home_id'); }
```

Club model:

```
public function match() { return $this->hasMany('Club', 'home_id'); }
```

Query:

```
$match = Match::with('club')->find(1);
```

Dump the name:

```
dd($match->club->name);
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an incomplete solution.  You would never find clubs that played as the away team.  In fact, club should belong to match not only based on home_id but also on away_id.

```
public function clubhome() { return $this->belongsTo('Match', 'home_id'); }
public function clubaway() { return $this->belongsTo('Match', 'away_id'); }
```

in your controller/router you can then join these into a single array to return the complete list.

I know this is messy but I'm dealing with the exact same issue and it's the only solution I've been able to come up with:

```
    //works: http://localhost:8080/match/4/clubs
    $one = Match::find($id)->clubhome();
    $two = Match::find($id)->clubaway();
    return Response::json(array($one,$two));
```